# paperclip with amazon s3 working in development but not working in production (amazon ec2)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, paperclip

I'm pretty new to rails and seem to be having an issue with the paperclip gem. I installed the gem and it works well in development (localhost:3000) but when I'm running it on the amazon server, for some reason it does not want to attach files, and the app breaks (error 500 page).

i have deployed my code to amazon server, i configured bucket details also, but still it is having problem with production, although it works fine with localhost.

Here is the process i ran... I pushed my file to amazon. This did not seem to help.

Here is the code that I have for paperclip:

user.rb model:

```
       has_attached_file :avatar,
                         :styles => {
                         :thumb  => "50x50",
                         :medium => "400x400",
                         :square => "70x70"
                                    },
      :storage => :s3,
      :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
      :path => ":attachment/:id/:style.:extension",
      :bucket => "mybucket"
```

my User form:

```
       <%= form_for(@user, url: "/sessions/#{current_user.id}", :html =>{:method => :put,       :class => "form-horizontal", :multipart => true}) do |f| %>
       <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
       <% end %>
```

breaks down in production. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated... I just cant seem to figure this out and it's pretty frustrating. Thank you so much for your time and any help! please give a pointer where i am making mistake.

Comment: So what's the error that is raised? (Check production.log)

Comment: @Frederick its showing something went wrong , nothing else, i am not getting what is problem with it..

Comment: but as i said it works fine with localhost, but it is not working with production environment..

Comment: That's all that's in production.log? If there's really no more, change the logging level and try again

Comment: Thanks Frederick, but can u please tell me how to see production.log , i new in Ruby on rails..
would be helpful..

Comment: It's a text file in your app's log folder.

Comment: @Frederick my production.log file   

Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Compiled jquery.js  (3ms)  (pid 7276)
Compiled jquery_ujs.js  (1ms)  (pid 7276)
Compiled rails.js  (0ms)  (pid 7276)
Compiled application.js  (268ms)  (pid 7276)
Compiled common.css  (2ms)  (pid 7276)
Compiled custom.css  (2511ms)  (pid 7276)
Compiled whytoworry.css  (0ms)  (pid 7276)
Compiled application.css  (2550ms)  (pid 7276)
Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL

Comment: i am not understanding anything by looking this one.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34278/discussion-between-karthick-m-and-frederick-cheung)

Comment: The information related to the most recent request is at the end of the log file

Comment: Thanks but should  check with my local directory or server directory???

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue with image_magic that was breaking our paperclip functionality in production, but not in development (weird, I know). Yet even after removing imagemagick from our gemfile and Gemfile.lock locally (running bundle install and all that stuff) and then deploying back to production on heroku, the error persisted in production! (weird, I know).

What ended up doing the trick was running:

```
$ heroku repo:purge_cache -a myAppName
```

(Taken from: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-repo#purge_cache)

When you deploy your app, Heroku caches some things like your assets and installed gems in order to speed up deployment. Although this is a great feature, it can have side-effects sometimes, and in this case, it seems that something about the imagemagick gem got "stuck" in production's cache, which is why purging solved the issue for us (since after purging, your app will rebuild itself from scratch on your next deployment)